# fwscanf_s strange behaviour in managed (and debug) compilations

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, clr

We are working with a DLL Library that has been compiled in VC++ as native for years. This DLL uses fwscanf_s without specifying the size of the parameters to be read (I already know this is wrong). The DLL was compiled with /RTC1 in debug mode and without it in release mode: both modes worked right.

Now, we have turned this DLL Library to be a managed one (compiled with /CLR) and we have removed the /RTC1 flag from debug compilation. The result is that fwscanf_s is not working anymore in debug mode (it works in release mode, also without /RTC1).

We have fixed it adding the size of the parameters to be read and now it works either in debug and in release mode, but we are still wondering this strange behaviour of fwscanf_s.

Does anybody has a idea?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Apparently, you have something like `fwscanf_s(f, "%s", p)`. The function then reads random garbage that happens to sit on the stack above `p`, and interprets it as the size of the buffer that `p` points to. If this random value happens to be large enough, the function would appear to work (but risk buffer overrun); if it happens to be smaller than the input, the function would, I think, truncate said input. Different compiler settings simply change stack usage patterns, which affects what random bytes are likely to sit on the stack near `p`.

Comment: Thanks Igor, that was our first thought also... But we think that the compiler should give warnings or exceptions (in run-time) about this, but we have no warnings nor exceptions... It's strange.

Comment: *"But we think that the compiler should give warnings or exceptions (in run-time)"* And what exactly makes you think so? How do you expect the function to determine that four bytes on the stack are not an integer deliberately placed there by the caller, but are just random garbage left behind by some prior stack activity?

Comment: You are totally right. I think that the coffee messed us :) Thanks Igor!